# How to translate a 3D object in javascript

Tags: javascript, list, for-loop, rotation, translation

I'm trying to do a simple rotation of a 3d object around its x-axis. The program sets up a fragment and vertex shader to use for objects in the WebGl program. The program contains the onLoad function which activates everything inside the function once the program is loaded in your web browser. First the function sets up the canvas to be used to hold the 3D object or objects to be used. Then I create my 3D block object that I am transforming and it is set at the origin by default. I'm creating a new list and filling it with all the vectors from the old list, while also applying a translation to each vector. I believe my problem is in the for loop with trying to apply the translation to every vector.

```
const vertex_shader = `
attribute vec4 vPosition;
attribute vec4 vColor;

uniform mat4 transform;

varying vec4 fColor;

void main()
{

gl_Position = transform * vPosition;

fColor = vColor;

gl_PointSize = 10.0;
}`;

const fragment_shader = `
precision mediump float;
varying vec4 fColor;

void main()
{
gl_FragColor = fColor; 
}`;



let params = {
transform: mat4(),
transformLoc: undefined,

maxVertices: 7000,

colors: undefined
};

function params_setup(gl, program) {
params.transformLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "transform");
gl.uniformMatrix4fv(params.transformLoc, false, flatten(params.transform));

// params.bands = 5;
// params.sides = 10;


}

window.onload = function init()
{

const lg = noLogging("Firebrick");
lg.insertAtEnd = false;

let canvas = document.getElementById( "gl-canvas" );

let gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL( canvas );
if ( !gl ) { alert( "WebGL isn't available" ); }
gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
// gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE);
gl.cullFace(gl.BACK);

//
//  Configure WebGL
//
gl.viewport( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
X11.clearColor(gl, X11.AliceBlue);


//  Load shaders and initialize attribute buffers
let program = initShaders( gl, vertex_shader, fragment_shader);
gl.useProgram( program );

params_setup(gl, program);

//creates the block object that will be transformed
 let blk = new cs4722_objects.Block();
blk.height = .75;
blk.width = .5;
blk.depth = .25;

let vertices = blk.points;
let colors = blk.color_scheme;

let trans = rotateX(45);

// modify vertices using the transformation here

let newList = [];

//I believe my problem resides in this for loop here
for(var i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++)
{
    newList.push(mult(trans, vertices[i]));
}
//to here

let bufferId = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferId );
gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 16*params.maxVertices, gl.STATIC_DRAW );
gl.bufferSubData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, flatten(vertices));


// Associate out shader variables with our data buffer
let vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vPosition" );
gl.vertexAttribPointer( vPosition, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vPosition );

let cBufferId = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cBufferId );
gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 16*params.maxVertices, gl.STATIC_DRAW );
gl.bufferSubData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, flatten(colors));
let vColor = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vColor" );
// four color components per color
gl.vertexAttribPointer( vColor, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vColor );


function render() {
            gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
            gl.drawArrays( gl.TRIANGLES, 0, vertices.length);
        };





render();
};
```

Comment: please share full code, could not say what the problem is

Answer (score 0):

Use it:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
#myDIV {
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: coral;
    color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click the "Try it" button to rotate the DIV element:</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div id="myDIV">
  <h1>myDIV</h1>
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    // Code for Safari
    document.getElementById("myDIV").style.WebkitTransform = "rotate(20deg)"; 
    // Code for IE9
    document.getElementById("myDIV").style.msTransform = "rotate(20deg)"; 
    // Standard syntax
    document.getElementById("myDIV").style.transform = "rotate(20deg)"; 
}
</script>

<p><b>Note:</b> Internet Explorer 9 supports an alternative, the msTransform property. Newer versions of IE and Edge support the transform property (do not need the ms prefix).</p>
<p><b>Note:</b> Safari supports an alternative, the WebkitTransform property.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'd love to, but i should have specified. I'm trying to accomplish this by only putting  code in the javascript file

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using `newList`. Your `mult` function returns new, modified vertex, so placing it in a new array is correct, but you are passing the unmodified `vertices` array to `gl.bufferSubData`.

Either:

- Replace your other references to `vertices` with `newList`
- Modify `vertices` in-place like `vertices = vertices.map(vert => mult(trans, vert));`

(I'm assuming your `mult` function comes from this template: http://ksuweb.kennesaw.edu/~bsetzer/4722fa18/nanoc/output/assignments/4/)

Comment: For a useful answer this reaction needs to be extended. Explain why this is an answer to the question.